# SQL remove a row based on condition

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure in Bigquery and a resulting table where 2 rows are not exactly duplicates but I want to filter one of the rows based on a condition.

SQL query:

[image: SQL query]

Results:

[image: check this table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH DupCodes AS (
  SELECT AccCode
  FROM Table
  GROUP BY AccCode
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (AccCode IN (SELECT AccCode FROM DupCodes) AND AccountName IS NOT NULL)
   OR (AccCode NOT IN (SELECT AccCode FROM DupCodes))
```

Comment: I guess, @Sin would like just to filter the rows out, not to remove them eternally from the table.

Comment: the title says "remove a row"?

Comment: the title says "I have a SQL <query?> result" :)

Comment: IDK actually, let's wait for clarification

Comment: Apologies, I would prefer to filter it out if possible

Comment: Not sure if `WITH` clause is a part of ANSI SQL. @Sin, which database are you using? If it's PostgreSQL, the answer should be fine for you. If not - it would be better to use subqueries instead.

Comment: I think it should work in MS SQL as well, but otherwise, yes, subqueries should work everywhere, I just don't like to violate the DRY principle

Comment: I am using Bigquery, I tried using the code above , it compiles ok but doesnt give me the expected result, still see both records in the table....I have a Stored Procedure  BEGIN ,......   end of SP, Your filter code, END

Comment: don't really have any experience with BigQuery, but apparently it does support the WITH clause.. one suggestion is to to try using IS NOT NULL instead of <> '', updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `not exists` logic:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.accountname is not null or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.accCode = t.accCode and t2.accountname is not null
                 );
```

That is, show all rows where `accountname` is not empty.  Then show empty rows only when there is no non-empty `accountname` for the same `accCode`.